# Python - Pandas filter and group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I need most similar column file, I have data:

Input:

[image: Input]

I need cluster-1 to be equal to cluster-2 in the maximum count, a file that will not be specified not to be included in the cluster

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: I am unable to understand the functionality you are trying to perform. Can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare first [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) per groups by original column, filter and if necessary add not filtered rows with assign `bin` to `cluster-2`:

```
print (df)
  file  cluster-1  cluster-2
0    A          1          2
1    D          1          2
2    G          2          4
3    B          3          1
4    E          3          2
5    J          3          1

m = (df.groupby('cluster-1')['cluster-2']
      .transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
      .eq(df['cluster-2']))
df = (df[m].append(df[~m].assign(**{'cluster-1':'bin'}), ignore_index=True)
          .rename(columns={'cluster-1':'cluster'})
          .drop('cluster-2', axis=1))
print (df)
  file cluster
0    A       1
1    D       1
2    G       2
3    B       3
4    J       3
5    E     bin
```

Comment: @PatrikNovotný - You are welcome! Btw, are you from Slovakia or Czech?

Comment: From Czech, děkuju, posílám pozdrav do Slovenska! :)